# Creating JSON-LD using GSON

Tags: json, gson, json-ld

I'm trying to read/write [JSON-LD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON-LD) documents using Gson. An example of JSON-LD:

```
{
  "@context": {
    "name": "http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/name",
    "homepage": {
      "@id": "http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/workplaceHomepage",
      "@type": "@id"
    },
    "Person": "http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/Person"
  },
  "@id": "http://me.markus-lanthaler.com",
  "@type": "Person",
  "name": "Markus Lanthaler",
  "homepage": "http://www.tugraz.at/"
}
```

The problem I have with Gson is adding the @ to the beginning of some of the fields. I tried using the [@SerializedName](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.2.3/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/annotations/SerializedName.html) annotation but I get errors:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: @context is not a valid JSON field name.
```

Without the "@" in the SerializedName annotation it works fine. Seems that Gson cannot handle the "@" even though it is valid JSON?

Comment: Which version of GSON are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the issue is your **Gson version**, it works at least for 1 year.

So please use the **latest version**, **[2.2.4](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/downloads/list)** from May, and it should just work.

Here is an example of strange things you can do:

```
static class A
{
    @SerializedName("@co.nte:xt|")
    public String s;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{       
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    A a = gson.fromJson("{ \"@co.nte:xt|\": \"s\"}", A.class);      
    return;
}
```