# Parsing JSON-LD in Android

Tags: android, json, api, parsing, json-ld

I am building an Android application.The API I am working with gives data in JSON-LD. I have never worked with JSON-LD before therefore am not sure how to parse this data. I have tried googling but there seems to be 0 results combining both Android and JSON-LD, only JSON.

I am not sure how I can use this API in my application

Please Help

Comment: You can parse it using gson: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17188543/creating-json-ld-using-gson

Comment: How exactly can I do that? I have downloaded the Gson jar file but am not sure how to use it?Do you have some code samples I can look at? The information on the internet is not really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check this out - https://github.com/jsonld-java/jsonld-java

Here is a sample code

```
// Open a valid json(-ld) input file
InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("input.json");
// Read the file into an Object (The type of this object will be a List, Map, String, Boolean,
// Number or null depending on the root object in the file).
Object jsonObject = JsonUtils.fromInputStream(inputStream);
// Create a context JSON map containing prefixes and definitions
Map context = new HashMap();
// Customise context...
// Create an instance of JsonLdOptions with the standard JSON-LD options
JsonLdOptions options = new JsonLdOptions();
// Customise options...
// Call whichever JSONLD function you want! (e.g. compact)
Object compact = JsonLdProcessor.compact(jsonObject, context, options);
// Print out the result (or don't, it's your call!)
System.out.println(JsonUtils.toPrettyString(compact));
```

Comment: Yes I did but didn't quite understand what was going on. Could you please explain it to me step by step? Or better yet, do you have code samples I can look at where you managed to parse JSON-LD in Android?